# Is it possible to modify a mutable vector when it is a key in HashMap?

Tags: rust

Here is my example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut my_map = HashMap::new();
    let mut my_vec = vec![5,6,7];    
    my_map.insert(my_vec, 4);

    // This part is fine, so I can create HashMap
    // with mutable Vector as key.

    my_vec.push(8);
}
```

However, I cannot actually modify the vector! `my_vec.push(8);` causes the following error:

```
post_test_19.rs:14:5: 14:11 error: use of moved value: `my_vec` [E0382]
post_test_19.rs:14     my_vec.push(8);
                       ^~~~~~
post_test_19.rs:7:19: 7:25 note: `my_vec` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<i32>`, which is non-copyable
post_test_19.rs:7     my_map.insert(my_vec, 4);
                                    ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Now the `HashMap` owns the `Vec`, so I cannot modify it.

As far as I understand, you cannot modify a `Vec` if it is used as key in `HashMap` even though it is technically mutable. Is my understanding correct? Is there a trick or a corner case that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot modify it, and even if you could, you absolutely should never do such a thing.

In your example, the reason you cannot modify the vector is because *you no longer own it*. You've transferred ownership of it to the map. That's what "use of moved value" means.

Let's say you had some way of modifying the key of the map (I'm not going to provide any examples to help prevent people from doing this). The main problem is that you'd be breaking an invariant of the `HashMap`:

> It is a logic error for a key to be modified in such a way that the key's hash, as determined by the Hash trait, or its equality, as determined by the Eq trait, changes while it is in the map.

The reason for this is simple once you understand how hashmaps work. When you add a key, an algorithm is run that converts the key into an integer (the key is *hashed*). Then, this integer is used to find a space in an array to store the value.

If you changed the key, then the value would be stored in the *wrong spot in the array*. As a simple example, imagine that the hashing algorithm for vectors was simply the number of items in the vector. If you added `vec![1]` as a key, it would be stored in array slot 1. If you then change the key, it *should* hash to 2, but would still be stored in slot 1!

Comment: Thanks. I know you should not do it, I was just curious, since this would be possible in `Ruby`, for example, I was just exploring how this works in `Rust`. `Rust` seems to be interesting in that you can have mutable types as keys (`Python` and `Go` would not allow it), but it you cannot change them later!

Comment: @Akavall you seem to be conflating the `mut` modifier on the binding with an innate property of the value itself. If you own a value, you can choose for it to be mutable or not.

Comment: @Akavall this is actually not possible in ruby. If you try to mutate a key in a ruby hash it will break the hash. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/ddebernardy/7629298

Comment: @Adrian that just shows that it is *possible* to mutate a key in a hash in Ruby. However, as you are pointing out, doing so makes it impossible to look up the key again. Likewise, it is *possible* to mutate the key in a hash in Rust, but it requires a bit more work. In the end, the hash will be in an inconsistent state as well.

Comment: @Adrian, you are totally right. The `Ruby` thing was the source of my confusion. Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid this all stems from a misunderstanding about what `mut` means.

You need to distinguish two terms:

- `vec![5, 6, 7]` produces an *instance* of the `Vec` type
- `my_vec` is a *binding*, that is to say, a name given to an instance of a type, because it's easier to manipulate instances by name (but not necessary, cue [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29))

When you declare `let mut my_vec`, you are:

- declaring a mutable *binding*
- to which an *instance* of `Vec` is bound

The *instance* itself cannot be called mutable, it is meaningless as illustrated by the following valid snippet:

```
let mut my_vec = vec![5, 6, 7];
let     other = my_vec;          // ownership transfer
let mut yac   = other;           // ownership transfer
```

In this snippet, we see:

- an *instance* of `Vec` type being bound to a mutable *binding* `my_vec`
- then being bound to an immutable *binding* `other`
- then being bound to a mutable *binding* `yac`

which hopefully showcases that mutability is a property not of the *instance* but the *binding*.

This is where *inherited mutability* comes into play:

- If you are in possession of a mutable *binding* to an *instance* of `T` (`let mut x: T = ...;`), or binding to a mutable reference to an *instance* of `T` (`let x: &mut T = ...;`), then you can not only mutate its fields, but also obtain mutable references to these fields to modify their own fields... recursively.
- And conversely, if all you hold is an immutable reference to an instance of type `T` (`let x: &T = ...;`), then all you can do is read its fields or obtain immutable references to these fields to read their own fields... recursively (*).

(*) Ok, Ok, it's a simplification, the `cell` types for example can be modified via immutable references; that's for another day!